# Prove $\binom{2n}{n}\geq\frac{4^n}{2n}$

Tags: combinatorics

I want to prove that$$\binom{2n}{n} \geq \frac{4^n }{ 2n}$$

I tried to solve with Stirling formula and got to 
$$\binom{2n}{n} \geq C*\frac{4^n}{ 2n}.$$ 
I'm not sure how to continue since $C$ could be between $0$ and $1$.  Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1772064/147873

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A classical inequality involving the central binomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2548770/a-classical-inequality-involving-the-central-binomial-coefficient) (see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614750/understanding-n-left-frac2n-choose-n4n-right2-for-large-n )

Answer (score 1):

Prove it by induction on $n$. When $n$ increases to $n+1$ the right-hand side increases by a factor of ${4n\over n+1}$  What about the left-hand side?